# Tag new Docker image push automatically for CI/CD deployment in Github Action

Tags: docker, github-actions, cicd

I want to be able to run a Github action that would build, automatically & uniquely tag and push an image to Docker hub.

I want it to also be that another Github action that deploys to the server will automatically know the image's tag and adds it to the image name to pull that specific image automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Publish Docker](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-docker) GitHub Action.

Example workflow that will trigger on new GH Release creation and will use the GH release version for tagging the Docker image:

```yaml
name: Publish to Registry
on:    
  release:
      types: [published]

jobs:
  update:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - id: pre-step
      shell: bash
      run: echo "release-version=$(echo ${GITHUB_REF:10})" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

    - name: Publish to Registry
      uses: elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action@v5
      with:
        name: myDocker/repository
        username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
        tags: "latest,${{ steps.pre-step.outputs.release-version }}"
```

Also, you can use `tag_names` when you want to push tags/release by their git name (e.g. `refs/tags/MY_TAG_NAME`):

```
with:
  name: myDocker/repository
  username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
  password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}
  tag_names: true
```

For more details visit the [Usage section](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-docker#usage).